# Stsadm command in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, stsadm

When i run stsadm command in my sharepoint server. This is the command i use

```
stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0
```

When I do that and click enter, I have a list of user profile service application. Out of which few of them are not synchronized for past many year. I am unable to find with the ID which is not synchronized. Is there a way to find the ID information or something. I am presenting few here now

> ID: acaf4489-f7d3-4ae1-9500-5f8d1cfc7944  Synchronized: 3/9/2011 10:00:02 AM
>
> ID: 124de97f-d229-4b8b-8105-d235d329a0a7  Synchronized: 2/27/2011 9:00:01 PM
>
> ID: 5e76cbd6-065a-4ecc-90d0-d53b3b6c6aef  Synchronized: 2/27/2011 4:00:01 PM

Please advise and help me solve this issue.

Comment: You have SharePoint Online tagged.  Is this an accident? You cannot use stasadm with SharePoint Online.

Comment: i added with purpose if people who used sharepoint 2010 in the past and had a solution it may also help. thats why

Comment: In that case tagging your question with "Sharepoint Online" is misleading. You should use the "2010" tag instead. Only use the tags your question **really** belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

To find out what databases the IDs correspond to, run:

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | Select ID,Name
```